# How do you constrain Visual studio Code Snippets to a type/class context?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constraints, code-snippets

In my project I use reflection to find and invoke certain (optional) methods, rather than defining an interface which forces the methods to be implemented. This is partly to support parameter dependency injection, which interfaces don't support very well, and partly for optimisation purposes (if the method isn't implemented, happy days, no invocation necessary).

However, without defining the methods within an interface or base class, there's no way IntelliSense can know to suggest those method names when you go to write the class. So, I thought of creating a visual studio extension, though I found no good guides to customizing IntelliSense. Instead, I thought Visual Studio Code Snippets might be the solution.

Code Snippets work nicely, but the one I created pops up everywhere. Even when I set the **Kind** attribute to *"method decl"* it still popped up outside of classes and inside methods etc. I don't want the snippet to appear everywhere, I only want it to appear inside a class, and preferably a class of a certain type (one that implements my interface, despite the interface not including the method declaration).

How, for instance, did Microsoft constrain the `ctor` snippet to only appear in classes? I looked at the snippet's XML but couldn't see anything to suggest it was constrained to classes, but we all know it is.

### Update

I don't think code snippets are sufficient for what I want. I am wanting to find out how to add custom IntelliSense, constrained to a certain type, like Unity does with their VS extension for instance. There's no good documentation online from what I've searched, and right now I'm stuck.

Comment: It sounds like you want to define a code fragment in Visual Studio so that it is prompted in a class. This is feasible. You only need to change the <stcut> to CTOR in the XML of the code fragment. As for why CTOR played such a role? You can understand it as a VS engineer in designing the code fragment, and pre -defines the type that the user may use in the code fragment. These types are recognized by Intellisense to recognize whether it needs to be prompted by SHORCUT.